# Hook into incoming call on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way to hook into the incoming phone call event and extract the number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge.. no.. This is because the "phone" app works within its own sandbox and therefore nothing from other applications can extract data out.. Also, I'm pretty sure its against the Terms and conditions of the appstore, so Apple wouldn't approve it.

It may be possible on a jailbroken phone, however I imagine it would be difficult to do..

Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

No, for security reasons you can't get info about incoming calls or SMS.

Comment: Well, I should be clearer. Apple does not provide APIs for accessing this information but you can get at it on a jailbroken device using iphonelogd or mobilesyncbrowser. Here's [more info](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2007/11/iphonelogd-another-solution-for-viewing-your-iphone-call-log.ars)